# Heroku does not support FreeType, what can we do about it?

Tags: heroku, gd, captcha, freetype

Heroku does not support FreeType, what can we do about it? 
I want to use securimage captcha, but i get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettfbbox() in /app/www/securimage.php on line 867

http://groups.google.com/group/heroku/browse_thread/thread/5f0b169272dd075f